# how does the value on the console appear in the gui tkinter?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I calculate the mean and standard deviation value with meanstds.py and call it into the gui Tkinter tk11.py, how to show value in window Tkinter not in console.

This my meanstds.py:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('sapi-sampel copy 1.png')
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
grey = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def aa():
    means, stds = cv2.meanStdDev(grey)
    RGB = rgb[100, 100]

    print(stds)
    print(means)
    print(RGB)

    if means < 100:
        print('ok')
    elif means >= 90:
        print('Mutu2')
    elif means < 60:
        print('Mutu3')
    else:
        print('more')

aa()
```

output meanstds :

mean : 69.23766717
stds : 80.40427734
rgb  : 55 15 14

This my tk11.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import meanstds

def openProgram():
    meanstds.aa()

Window = Tk()
Window.geometry('400x400')

B = Button(text = "Run Program", command = openProgram).pack()
Window.mainloop()
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? All of the tkinter widgets are documented, and every tutorial shows you how to use them.